# how to jquery replace space also

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).html().replace("0 days","");
```

i want to replace "0 days" to become "". Currently the above statement will replace "0" to "" . that is not what i want. i want to replace entire statement "0 days"

Comment: What you have *should* work, do you have an example page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/jrJga/

works fine here..

Answer (score 3):

This will replace only the first occurrence. If you want to replace all occurrences:

```
$(this).html().replace(/0 days/g, '');
```

Example:

```
alert('foo 0 days bar 0 days foobar'.replace(/0 days/g, ''));
```

shows:

```
foo bar foobar
```

Comment: Not my downvote - but, while this is correct, it doesn't really explain his current behavior of replacing the `"0"` but not the `" days"` portion...

Comment: he wants to replace all the given words with a single empty character, or null, or simply remove them

Comment: @Nick, this behavior is inexplicable from what the OP provided as information. I gave a counter example for this.

Comment: I concur, what he posted doesn't make any sense given the provided code, something outside the question going on here.